# Best way to block out UI elements when editing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I would like some suggestions on how best to handle 'blurring out' non essential UI elements during editing. To explain this more clearly I have produced a diagram:

[image]

Our web application uses JQuery dialog windows to view/edit data. Most of our data is categorized within JQuery accordions which sit inside such the draggable windows.

When the user clicks on the edit button of an accordion header, we would like to block out everything on the page apart from the accordion content being edited.

Having tried such plugins as 'Block UI' (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) we have been unable to achieve this. With 'Block UI' we can only 'blur out' the whole UI and display a modal message...

It's become apparent that the functionality we are looking for may not be possible this way.

Essentially whilst a user is editing form details in a given DIV, all other outside elements must not be 'clickable' until the user saves or discards changes. (Ideally like the window on the right)

**Are there any suggestions on the best way to implement such functionality?**

Comment: Easiest way would be to just have an element (with semi-transparent background) overlaying the whole page (position fixed, or absolute for mobile devices) – and have that one section you want to be still usable placed on top of that, by positioning it as well (relative) and giving it a higher z-index.

Comment: I think the idea that you are looking for is this: http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/expose/form.html but doing it just in jQuery or are you wanting to use jquerytools library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Tools expose should do what you need: http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html
On the [download page](http://jquerytools.github.io/download/), you can select only expose, which is 0.6 Kb gzipped.

Comment: Seems like what OP is looking for

Comment: "jQuery Tools expose" link offline

Answer (score 1):

You could overlay a div as expected, then access the element(s) you want active and move them to the front using relative positioning and z-index.

Presuming you wanted to access only a `button` element:

```
$('<div />').css({
    background: '#000000',
    opacity: 0.5,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    zIndex: '10'
}).appendTo('body');
$('button').css({
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 20
});
```

**[Here's an example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nRWXK/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

NB: this post assumes you want to use Block UI, or that you would at least benefit from its key ability to prevent *all user interaction* (including keyboard navigation); the way you've phrased your question (and the way others seem to be answering it) is that you want to prevent people from simply *clicking* elsewhere. It's an important difference!

You can use Block UI to block the whole page except the parts you want the user to use, then unblock the parts you want the user to focus on.

```
void function blockRest(){
    function getRest(target){
        var andParent = target.add(target.parents());

        return andParent.siblings();
    }

    $.fn.blockRest   = function(){
        getRest(this).block();

        return this;
    }

    $.fn.unblockRest = function(){
        getRest(this).unblock();

        return this;
    }
}();
```

This way, taking out everything except the post editor on StackOverflow becomes:

```
$('#post-editor').blockRest();
```

Bear in mind you'll need to use `unblockRest` to clear it afterwards.

If you don't like the styling BlockUI applies, you can nerf it with this object as the argument the calls to `block` and `unblock`:

```
{message:null,overlayCSS:{opacity:0,cursor:'default'}}
```